# Send variable from JavaScript into Flask

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, post, flask

I'm a complete beginner here and facing a problem in passing javascript variable into flask. Please note that my question is completely different from previous question that has been asked.

This is my code:

**JavaScript**

```
var dd = {'mvar': 1};

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "/",
      data: JSON.stringify(dd),
      success: function (data) {
        alert("DONE!")
      },
      dataType: "json"
    });
```

**Flask(edited)**

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new():

  form = InputForm(request.form)
  v = request.get_json().get('mvar')
  print(v)

  return render_template('new.html',form=form,v=v)
```

However, when the output that I get when print out the result is "**None**" while I expected it to be "**1**"

Really hope that experts can help me, thank you!

Comment: You can using javascript set value of `mvar` to session and get value of session in flask

Comment: Can you teach me how to do it? I did not learn on session yet

Comment: I'm not good at JavaScript. Do you know how to set session variable like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/702558/set-session-values-using-javascript). To get session variable in Flask, refer [Flask session](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions)

Comment: I'm not sure how it gonna be

Answer (score 2):

The [**Request.get_json()**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.get_json) method is what you are looking for in your Flask code.

```
data = request.get_json()
```

**edit** here is the exact pattern i use which works:

#### javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ url_for("get_post_json") }}",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({hello: "world"}),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

#### python:

```
@app.route('/_get_post_json/', methods=['POST'])
def get_post_json():    
    data = request.get_json()

    return jsonify(status="success", data=data)
```

Comment: but where do I put the name of variable in javascript here?

Comment: you don't... a POST is different than a GET in that it has a data payload which will get parsed by that function into the data variable "en masse" (as a python dict in this case which should essentially match the structure of your javascript object)....

Comment: I already tried using get_json just now and got the same "None"

Comment: I already copied your way of doing it but it printed out "<Response 5 bytes [200 OK]> "

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
v = request.form.get('mvar', type=int)
```

Use this

```
v = request.get_json().get('mvar')
```

Once you print v then you should get it.

Comment: it shows this error ---->    
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Update your question with the view function (the function that has __v = request.get_json().get('mvar')__ line )

Comment: Change this url: "{{ url_for("get_post_json") }}" to url: "/testing" and then, @app.route("/_get_post_json/") to @app.route("/testing"). Just a try

Comment: Are you seing the right edit @Nabin ?? My edit is the most top not above you -_-

Comment: Your page url is "/" and ajax request is also in "/". Is that what you want?

Comment: Are you getting alert with "DONE" message?

Comment: It means, you are very much lost here :D. The ajax request is not called what so ever and you are expecting Flask to do something. First try to fire ajax request.

Comment: Can you edit your answer ? I'm really confused on doing ajax request

Comment: There are many tutorials on internet. Find some good one and come back when you have any issue there

Comment: i dont know what to find because i dont know where i'm wrong :D